# Can't use PSQL with a Heroku shared database

Tags: heroku, postgresql

I'm developing an application and hosting it on Heroku. For now, I want to use the free shared database solution.

My problem is that I can't access the database.

```
$ heroku pg:psql
 !    Cannot ingress to a shared database
```

I've read elsewhere that I can't connect to shared databases via psql.

I can't seem to find any information on that on Heroku's Dev Center, so this leaves me with the question - how can I edit or change or do anything with my database?

Comment: That restriction seems to be mentioned here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy to use a beta addon then there is the Heroku Shared PostgreSQL 9.1 addon (https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-shared-postgresql) which will permit you to ingress to your database.

However, any changes to your database are usually best done with scripted migrations (in the Ruby on Rails world) rather than connecting to your database to make changes.

If you're more familiar with mySQL then there are a number of mySQL addons which permit direct access also with normal mySQL tools.

Comment: As of right now I can't add that ("Basic coming soon"), but that would be good for me. I'm going to wait and see, if anyone else has something to offer, otherwise I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: If you're logged into heroku.com you can add it from the link above - it's a public beta. If you're not logged in you see 'Coming soon'

Comment: I'm logged in but I can't add it :-(